# Clustering-based Identification

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms

I am trying to find a way to merge data that correspond to users and have the form

$user_i, property_1, property_2, .\dots, property_n$, where $n\geq50$, $i\geq 10^6$

We might have missing data in some cases (i.e. $property_k$ might be missing for some users), or we might have two or more users (lines in the database) that correspond to the same user, and the only difference is some small variation in some of their properties.

Specifically, I am interested in finding what is the cluster that a user belongs to, using some machine learning algorithm, etc. Each cluster will have all the instances of a user (all the lines that correspond to him). For that, we need of course some distance metric, which will depend on the model, I guess.

Any ideas on what is the best model for such a system?

Comment: You first have to find out how to measure similarity of users. Many algorithms can work with any similarity.

Comment: Any specific suggestion that can work with big datasets?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is "entity resolution" -- recognizing that John Smith, with social security number 123-34-5678 is probably the same as John **Q.** Smith with social security number 123-34-5678.